# Making an ajax post request in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to submit a form via ajax and post to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` but I am getting response code 400.

I am submitting the form as so:

```
$.ajax("/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", {
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: form_data,
  success : function(response) {
    console.log('working', responseText)
  },
  error: function(err){
    console.log('err', err)
  }
});
```

On my Wordpress backend I simply have an action and my handler function:

```
function panacea_form_process() {
    // do whatever you need in order to process the form.
    return 'working';
}

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_panacea_form", "panacea_form_process");
```

I was following this guide - https://teamtreehouse.com/community/submitting-a-form-in-wordpress-using-ajax but have tried to simplify it for debugging purposes.

I tried having a nonce but believe I don't require it as that is only needed for users who are logged in?

Hitting a wall so any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

Have added localize script:

```
wp_localize_script( "_main-sripts",
    'theUniqueNameForYourJSObject',
    array(
      'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( "randomstring" ),
    )
  );
```

Updated my ajax call with localized admin url and also action name etc

```
$.ajax(theUniqueNameForYourJSObject.admin_url, {
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data : {action: "panacea_form", form_data : form_data, nonce: theUniqueNameForYourJSObject.nonce},
  success : function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    console.log('working', responseText)
  },
  error: function(err){
    console.log('err', err)
  }
});
```

Updated my action to return using wp_send_json and to include the action for logged in users:

```
function panacea_form_process() {
    // do whatever you need in order to process the form.
    wp_send_json('working');
}

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_panacea_form", "panacea_form_process");
add_action("wp_ajax_panacea_form", "panacea_form_process");
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried having a nonce but believe I don't require it as that is only
>   needed for users who are logged in?

Nonce - is required. Request will be more securely.
What about your `form_data`? This should be json or request string.

And

```
function panacea_form_process() {
    // do whatever you need in order to process the form.
    return 'working';
}
```

Must have an `echo`, not return. Use [wp_send_json()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/) for returning data. Or [wp_send_json_success()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/) for success results or [enter link description here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/) for failed.

Comment: 'Request will be more securely' thus it's not required but advised.

Comment: Have added wp response handler function and also included action name in the ajax request along with some other changes. Have added my changes to OP. Unfortunately still getting the same error response of 400

Comment: Check [this topick](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/400-bad-request-on-admin-ajax-php-only-using-wp-enqueue-scripts-action-hook)

Comment: @MaximSarandi not working. Getting same result of 400 response

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem probably comes from the fact that you're missing an action.
You're using `add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_panacea_form", "panacea_form_process");` but the `wp_ajax_nopriv` is for non privileged users. Or users that are not logged in to the website/wp-admin

Since you're developing the site you're probably logged and so AJAX calls that should work for both logged-in en non-logged-in users you need another action so change is to
`add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_panacea_form", "panacea_form_process");
add_action("wp_ajax_panacea_form", "panacea_form_process");`

Other then that you should echo results from AJAX calls, returning doesn't work properly in this case. Ideally you'd use `wp_send_json` as well.

Tip:
You should [localize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) your ajax URL from where you enqueue the script to ensure the call still works when wp-admin is renamed.

Comment: Have added the section action hook and have also tried not being logged in but getting the same error response of 400. Have edit OP to show my changes

Comment: The handle you are localizing is `_main-sripts` is this a typo for 'scripts' because if so, that typo is the reason it's still not working

Comment: Did you need any other help or is your problem solved?